# How to increase a width of an element through CSS?

Tags: css, web, menubar

Currently I am working on a maintenance of website and I'm stuck with an problem, the problem is like that: I have to redesign the **menu bar** of the website. Previously in the menu bar there are 6 menus but now there are only 5 menus in it. I have to **delete one menu item** from the bar. I simply deleted that row from the list items of the menu bars. In the previous designed they used the [**display**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) property of css to create the blocks but after deleting the one menu the space for one menu item is left, while i like to increse the width of the menu bar.

Comment: please give some code to understand better

Comment: so is there a huge space on the right on the menu bar?

Comment: it would help if you give us the current html and css for the menu

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code, it is hard to say.

However, in your stylesheet you can adjust the `width` for the list items as such

`.menu li{width:35px;}`

To figure out how much to adjust, take the `width` of the last element and divide by 5 (the number of the remaining list elements).

So, if your `width` was `50px`, add `10px` to the element style so that each of the remaining elements covers the width of your previous `list-item`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a brute way to this but it actually works great:
Use table instead of list. I use this with some padding offset because spaces between cells are linear based on cell content size and padding gives you constant minimal space between menu elements.

Another way is to use block elements and CSS display:table and table-cell but remember IE7 does not know these ones.

Benefits: no Javascript

Answer (score 0):

If the menu item `<li>` has a fixed width, then the total width of the menu divided by 5 gives the width of the each menu item. check in the css for the tag "li"  or the class specified for li. then change the width of that to the new width

Comment: width for **<li>** is set to auto.